# GGTS 3.4.0 unable to recognize grails specific classes

Tags: grails, groovy

I created a new Grails project in GGTS 3.4.0. But whenever I am going to import any grails specific class, it's not recognized and I am getting error.

For example, I tried to import `grails.rest.Resource`, but GGTS is showing an error: **Groovy:unable to resolve class grails.rest.Resource**

What might be the problem? I cleaned the project and refreshed dependencies multiple times, but no help!

Any help/suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thanks folks!

**UPDATE**

I could resolve the problem by updating the grails version to 2.3.6 as `grails.rest.Resource` was added in grails 2.3 as suggested by tim_yates.

Comment: That class was added to grails 2.3 what version are you using?

Comment: I am using Grails 2.2 currently..downloading 2.3.6 right now. But I am unable to import any of the grails classes. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I am wondering what **grails classes** are. Grails is a framework. You can create a **grails project** by rely on GGTS.And a grails project can contain classes such as **.java** , **.groovy**.

About the error you mentioned, I guess a situation.

- You added a dependency in **BuildConfig.groovy**. This dependency contains classes that you will use in your code.
- But, you **DID NOT** *refresh dependencies* (in GGTS 3.4, selecct *Grails tools > refresh dependencies* ).

So, when you refresh dependencies, all dependencies you declared in **BuildConfig.groovy** will be resolved and loaded to the project classpath.

By this way, your code now can use the classes in the dependency you declared in the BuildConfig.groovy file.

So, I guess that you only declared a dependency contains class **grails.rest.Resource**, but you didn't perform refresh dependencies. Therefore, you can not use the class **grails.rest.Resource** in your code anymore.

Hope this help.

Comment: As I said I have refreshed the dependencies multiple times, but it does not help. By grails classes I mean, the annotations and groovy classes that ship as a part of grails framework. However, I could resolve the issue by updating the grails version to 2.3.6 as suggested by tim_yates.

Answer (score 0):

## STEP1:

[image]

## STEP2 (run : refresh-dependencies):

[image]

### if does not work after that ,check your `BuilConfig.groovy` file .